# Can I use the drive URL to copy a folder with rclone?

Tags: rclone

Rather than navigate through the folder structure I'd find it easier to just use the drive URL that I could copy from  - for example Firefoy. Like this:

```
rclone copy https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/some_id_from_gdrive .
```

Is it possible? or is it possible via some part of the URL?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You talk about folder structure which says to me local computer and give an example of a web site.

Comment: @David - In rclone the typical command uses some sort of hierarchical file structure also on the remote,. However on google drive that is a mapping to a URI that contains an ID. My question is: can I skip the folder navigation and point straight to the ID? I hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

```
rclone copy --drive-root-folder-id some_id_from_gdrive source: /path/to/your/local/folder -Pv
```

"source:" is your Google Drive remote name.